# Mapping between two classes with JpaRepository SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Well I have a class Service and a class Employee

`Service.java`

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Table(name = "services")
@Entity
public class ServiceResource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    private EmployeeResource employee;


}
```

`Employee.java`

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Table(name = "employees")
@Entity
public class EmployeeResource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;


}
```

Now I'd like to build my application that the mapping between service and employee is done with JPA. Is that even possible and how?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your EmployeeResource Entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ServiceResource> serviceList;
```

and in ServiceResource, modify the join column like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private EmployeeResource employee;
```